# Загрузить изображение в ImageButton

Tags: android

Есть кнопка ImageButton. Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на нее открывалась галерея (или камера чтобы сфоткать) и когда пользователь выберет фотографию (или сфоткает) она становилась иконкой этой кнопки (или фоном). Затем эту картинку выбранную пользователем нужно сохранять в БД (сохранение в БД умею делать).

Наверное выбранное или сфотканное фото нужно куда-то в папку приложения загружать? Как вообще такое реализуется?

Comment: А код у вас есть? Какой-нибудь?

Comment: Нет, пока даже не знаю с чего начать..

Comment: Тогда вам не сюда, а, например, сюда http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/imagebutton.php (на SO приходят когда уже дым из ушей идет)

Comment: как реализовать клик на кнопку я знаю.. Меня интересует работа с галереей и камерой в данном случае.

Comment: Тогда в гугл и читать, читать. Потом что-нибудь написать и если что, то сюда прийти

Comment: Пока что код мне не нужен. На словах хотелось бы узнать каков алгоритм действий.. Пока что при нажатии на кнопку у меня такой код                  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

Comment: в замечательной книге Б.Филлипса ["Android. Программированияюе для профессионалов"](https://m.habr.com/ru/company/piter/blog/335146/) очень подробно разбирается такой пример (приложение Criminal Intent).  и работа с камерой и вывод полученного изображения в список. А здесь помогают с конкретной проблемой обычно, а не общими направлениями

Answer (score 0):

Частично ответ на этот вопрос есть в книге Дэрси, Кондер "Андроид за 24 часа" 13 глава.

Создать два слушателя нажатий для камеры и галереи. Потом реализовать метод `onActivityResult()`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { .. }
```

Для камеры и для галереи.
И обработать результаты этого метода во вспомогательном методе.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]